# String appended to File converted to special charecters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file

I am trying to write a some string to a file.

```
        string lines = "server.1=1.1.1.1:9999\nserver.2=2.2.2.2:8888\n";
        File.AppendAllText(directory_path + "zoo.cfg", lines);
```

The string printed in the file is

> "敳癲牥ㄮㄽㄮㄮㄮ㤺㤹ਹ敳癲牥㈮㈽㈮㈮㈮㠺㠸ਸ"

. 
I tried with encoding ASCII,UTF-8,DEFAULT in the File.AppendAllText. But the output is the same.

Environment:

> Visual studio 2015, Windows server 2012, .net v4.5

Please let me know what Iam doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? The code you have posted works without error and creates the proper text in the file.

Comment: What is the encoding of the existing file? How do you _read_ it?

Comment: That's not what I asked at all. Read my comment again and answer both questions properly.

Comment: @stuartd This is the reason i posted this question here. It works just perfect on my other machine. Is this something got to do with machine or VS or .net versioning ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use Path.Combine, never use + to build up paths with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now this is weird. The code given above works perfect on my other machine. But for some reason which i don't know it's not working in my new dev env. 
I solved the issue by adding the **Encoding.Unicode** parameter.

`File.AppendAllText(windows_directory_path + "zoo.cfg", lines, Encoding.Unicode);`

No idea why **Encoding.UTF8/Encoding.ASCII** didn't change the format for the resulting string.

Still wondering how same code could behave so differently.

I'm not sure if this is fix or a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Appending doesn't rewrite the entire file. So, you have to use the same encoding as the existing content.

In general, if you don't know the encoding of text, you might as well not have that text. If someone gave it to you, "send it back." When they send it to you, it has to be accompanied by a mutual understanding of the encoding used. (BTW-It's very unlikely that it would be ASCII. And `Encoding.Default` is useless from machine to machine or user to user.)

Given the result, it makes complete sense that the file encoding was UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode`). Writing using any other encoding is garbage code.